# Can an aws sub account have it's own sub account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible for an aws sub account to have its own child account or is this only possible from the root account? My situation is that I am getting a number of aws credits that I would like to apply for a specific subset of users. Ideally I would create a separate account for these users so I can track their charges in an isolated environment. However, I would like the aws credits to be used for both accounts current and new sub account. Any idea if this is possible?

I do not have access to the root account, but have admin access to the current sub account.